# Scala on Android, a server client architecture

Tags: android, scala, networking, rpc

I'm creating a game with Scala and I would like to know how to do neatly the network part. My game is a strategic game which is composed by orders that are case class.

By exemple `Move(from:(Int,Int), to:(Int,Int)) extends Order`.

When in a multiplayer game, the android client should receive an order with an id containing the id from the player that made that move and send his own moves. I want to use a central server to each every client connect. So basically, a client should be able to log on the server, to send enough information to create a game on the server, to ask the list of the game, and to join a new game, but also to receive serialized data from the server, and case class.

I saw that `finagle` was a good option, my problem is I have some trouble with finagle on Android and it can only receive data after asking for them, so i have to do a "Refresh" packet every x to keep the client updated.